# How to write colored text into a static control in a dialog?

Tags: win32gui

Using win32 api...

I want to write a bright red error message into a static text control, but other static controls in the dialog must not come out red too. I want this kind of error message for several dialogs that are created by the Visual Studio 2015 dialog editor. It is too late now to change that, e.g. by using CreateWindow for each control instead.

I created a different win32 C++ project (I named it colorstatic) from Visual Studio and used the 'About colorstatic' dialog generated by the Studio to experiment. This dialog has two lines 'colorstatic, Version 1.0.' and 'Copyright (C) 2016' created by Visual studio with identical ids `IDC_STATIC`. I renamed the first static control to `IDC_STATICERRORMSG` and left the second as `IDC_STATIC`. I can output error messages to the first control in black that is the default colour for dialogs as far as I know, but the error message static control really must have a different colour to stand out.

1. I read about `WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC` message but have never used it or seen examples using it.
   Documentation says this message is sent to the parent. I assume this means the dialog callback procedure, so I placed case `WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC` in the About dialog proc before the `WM_COMMAND`, but it was never called. I also placed another `WM_CTLCOLORTATIC` in the main windowproc, but that was not called either.
2. I also saw a suggestion (googling) to use Ownerdraw, but I could not find ownerdraw as a Visual Studio option. Is there a way to change the style attribute to ss_ownerdrawitem for a static control created by the dialog editor?
3. I also tried subclassing the `IDC_STATICERRORMSG` control, but did not get anywhere.

I am stuck and I help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a skeleton program that achieves it. It's strange that you should not receive the WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC message, for all I'm doing is handling it.

If you have a peek at the docs for the message, you see that one is expected to return the handle of a brush used to draw the background if the message is handled. This presents us with a problem - the dialog callback proc expects a bool. So, while we can get away with using this function in a dialog, it seems that it wasn't really intended to be. A good choice of background would seem to be to actually query the parent. Doing so however, gives us a value that when returned, prevents colour change. Using a hollow-brush changes the text colour, but the background is affected too. Hmm.

When we do achieve a colour change, we get a poorly coloured background. So, we need to set the background-mode of the text to transparent, which kills two birds with one stone. It frees us from returning anything other than true/false from the dialog proc and also avoids a discoloured text background. Beauty.

[image]

### resource.h

```
#ifndef IDC_STATIC
#define IDC_STATIC (-1)
#endif

#define DLG_MAIN                                100
#define IDC_ERRORMSG                            40000
```

### resource.rc

```
// Generated by ResEdit 1.6.2
// Copyright (C) 2006-2014
// http://www.resedit.net

#include <windows.h>
#include <commctrl.h>
#include <richedit.h>
#include "resource.h"

//
// Dialog resources
//
LANGUAGE LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_NEUTRAL
DLG_MAIN DIALOG 0, 0, 186, 95
STYLE DS_3DLOOK | DS_CENTER | DS_MODALFRAME | DS_SHELLFONT | WS_CAPTION | WS_VISIBLE | WS_POPUP | WS_SYSMENU
CAPTION "Dialog"
FONT 8, "Ms Shell Dlg"
{
    LTEXT           "Static", IDC_ERRORMSG, 39, 43, 125, 8, SS_LEFT, WS_EX_LEFT
    LTEXT           "Error", IDC_STATIC, 7, 43, 19, 8, SS_LEFT, WS_EX_LEFT
}

//
// Manifest resources
//
LANGUAGE LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_NEUTRAL
1                  RT_MANIFEST    ".\\manifest.xml"
```

### main.cpp

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <commctrl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "resource.h"

HINSTANCE hInst;

BOOL CALLBACK DlgMain(HWND hwndDlg, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(uMsg)
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
    {
    }
    return TRUE;

    case WM_CLOSE:
    {
        EndDialog(hwndDlg, 0);
    }
    return TRUE;

    case WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC:
    {
        if (GetDlgCtrlID((HWND)lParam) == IDC_ERRORMSG )
        {
            HBRUSH retVal = (HBRUSH) GetStockObject(HOLLOW_BRUSH);
            SetTextColor( (HDC)wParam, RGB(255,0,0) );
            SetBkMode( (HDC)wParam, TRANSPARENT);
            return (BOOL)retVal;
        }
    }
    return 0;


    case WM_COMMAND:
    {
        switch(LOWORD(wParam))
        {
        }
    }
    return TRUE;
    }
    return FALSE;
}


int APIENTRY WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd)
{
    hInst=hInstance;
    InitCommonControls();
    return DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(DLG_MAIN), NULL, (DLGPROC)DlgMain);
}
```

Comment: Your example was just spot on. It helped me to find the cause of the problem.
I wanted to see if the case WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC would be called so I placed a break statement as case code and set a debug breakpoint at it. It was not called. Maybe the break statement had been optimised away by the compiler, since the debugger stopped on other executable code, e.g. return 0, assignments etc.
Many thanks.